# Confirmation Message [Type 'AK'] and ConfirmationAck Message [Type 'AU']

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I am using **Quickfixn** to create **Buy side application** and using the **Quickfix 4.4**.I am looking for creation of **Confirmation message( type 'AK' )** and **ConfirmationAck message [type 'AU']**.Can anyone tell me how is the flow of the **confirmation message[type 'AK']**  and **ConfirmationAck [type 'AU']**?? And can anyone also provide me with sample **Confirmation message** and **ConfirmationAck message** or the links,websites regarding it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiximate is the website you can refer to to check the message structure and what all fields represent](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/).

I am currently dealing with Allocation Instruction(J) messages which send out AK and AU messages. You send acoss a new trade message to your counterparty(broker). Your broker sends and ack(P) and tries to fulfill your order.

When the order is fulfilled, they will send across AK to confirm your order has been fulfilled. Next step is you decide if you accept the allocations assigned to you. If you are happy/not happy with the allocations you send across AU saying you accept(reject) the allocations and want the allocations to be redone, if required. This is how the message flows.

Comment: Good answer, except missing one important point:  **You really need to consult your counterparty's documentation.**  That'll tell you exactly what they expect in an AK message, including any custom or special fields they want.  It'll tell you exactly how they use AK and AU messages.